# Check if row contains word

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a spreadsheet and I only want to select rows that have a specific word in one column and another word in another column. At the moment I am only able to check for the word in any cell in the row. How can I check for the presence of the word in a cell in a specific column?

Here is my code

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath));
XSSFWorkbook      workBook = new XSSFWorkbook (fis);
XSSFSheet         sheet    = workBook.getSheetAt (0);

List<XSSFRow> filteredRows = new ArrayList<XSSFRow>();
Iterator<Row> rows= sheet.rowIterator(); 
while (rows.hasNext ()){
    XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) rows.next ();  

    Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator (); 
    while (cells.hasNext ()){

        XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next (); 
        if (cell.toString().contains("Ginko")) {
            filteredRows.add(row);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know which column (index or by name) that needs to be looked into?

Comment: Yes. By name, and if necessary by header

Comment: and by number in the row

Comment: Why not [use the index-based method for iterating your rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if a cell is in a specific column by calling `cell.getColumnIndex() == columnNumber`. For example:

```
for(Cell cell : row) {
  if(cell.getColumnIndex() == 1) {
    // process a cell in column 1
  }
}
```

Source: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getColumnIndex()

Comment: Must be doing something dumb but I dont get .getAddress as method for cell

Comment: Hmm what is your dependency version for POI? The method doc says "since 3.14beta1".

Comment: Actually I just realized there is a `#getColumnIndex` method. I updated my answer to use that as it is more direct.